# Google App Engine with PHP 7 Support

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Currently, PHP runtime on Google App Engine is available for every developer. However, it is PHP version 5.5.xx. Even though Google Cloud team have introduced a ManagedVMs, which allows developer to flexibly set up and customize runtime environment. Anyway, there is no evidence of customizable PHP in ManageVMs. The only way for now is moving to Compute Engine or Container Engine instead.

I want to figure out the Google Cloud team's road map about the future of PHP in Google App Engine where allow developer to focus on building the scalable application in more fast, more secure, more advanced syntax such as PHP7.

Comment: The need to upgrade has become more urgent now that PHP 5.5 is no longer supported by the PHP group.  If you want to use app engine you're stuck with an unsupported and potentially insecure version of PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got PHP7 for Google App Engine up and running quite quickly.
Follow this tutorial and see the Git

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php

Basically it's a composer.json file where you specify your PHP version and a app.yaml file

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

Google App Engine creates a Docker container(s) from your project and deploys them to the Flexible Environment on GAE.

Comment: Thanks, I've it last night from Google Next '17. It works now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can run PHP 7 on Google App Engine flexible environment. The PHP support is still early (beta) and the [documentation and samples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/) are still being developed. Alternatively, you can use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/) on the flexible environment and run your own dockerfile of your choosing.

Comment: your 'custom runtime' href is a link to Google's Moma intranet.

Comment: Fixed the link.

Comment: Now Google App Engine flexible environment is GA! The PHP runtime is still in Beta, but we're working on the GA release.

Comment: Good catch Takashi. Edited to remove the disclaimer about the whole environment being beta.

Comment: if php7 going to be made available for gae standard, flex is pricy for start projects.

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo any idea when PHP 7 will be coming to the App Engine Standard environment? :)

Comment: There is an open issue related to the standard environment that also links to a form for an early alpha access here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900606